# Android 2.2 : How add device admin

Tags: 2.2-froyo, device-administrator

I can't figure out how to add / remove device admins from my HTC Desire running Android 2.2

Where in the settings screen is this feature located ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be located under Android Settings > Location & Security.

But you need apps that support this feature in order to make full use of it. If you have a Google Apps or an exchange account your admin will be able to use the corresponding features like password reset etc.

Certain apps (examples: Llama / WidgetLocker / WaveSecure) when made as device administrators are then allowed a higher level of access to system features.

Comment: Yes I saw this in certain posts... but the issue is.. i have not such menu option. I have Security and Location separately, and neither of those options expose device admin to me.